# Redirecting input from file to command-line program

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection

I have a command-line program that normally gets its parameters from the keyboard after the program is run. Something like this:

```
Enter parameter 1? 3
Enter parameter 2? 2.6
Calculate something y/n? y
```

Rewriting the program to take command-line parameters is not possible.

I'd like to time how long it takes to execute the program with a batch file that is similar to the following:

```
@echo %time%
program.exe < params.txt
@echo %time%
```

The problem is that for some reason, the final parameter does not get accepted.

Note that the final parameter is a y/n, and I have added an empty line at the end so there is a newline after the y/n.

The input file, `params.txt`:

```
3
2.6
y
*empty line*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate interactive command line programs using [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Here's an example (for telnet) from the Wikipedia article

```
# Assume $remote_server, $my_user_id, $my_password, and $my_command were read in earlier 
# in the script.
# Open a telnet session to a remote server, and wait for a username prompt.
spawn telnet $remote_server
expect "username:"
# Send the username, and then wait for a password prompt.
send "$my_user_id\r"
expect "password:"
# Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
send "$my_password\r"
expect "%"
# Send the prebuilt command, and then wait for another shell prompt.
send "$my_command\r"
expect "%"
# Capture the results of the command into a variable. This can be displayed, or written to disk.
set results $expect_out(buffer)
# Exit the telnet session, and wait for a special end-of-file character.
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

It should be clear that you can use this approach for your program as you know the prompt strings and you know what responses to feed it.

Comment: Note that apparently, in order to use this answer, you may need to have additional software ([TCL](http://www.tcl.tk/)?, [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)?) installed in your environment.